# how to `.Take()` on a string and get a string at the end?

Tags: c#, linq, string, linq-to-objects, take

LINQ to Objects supports queries on string objects but when I use code such as below:

```
string SomeText = "this is some text in a string";
return SomeText.Take(6).ToString();
```

All I get is:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+<TakeIterator>d__3a`1[System.Char]
```

This is discussed as an "accident" in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702390/how-can-i-evaluate-a-deferred-linq-statement-when-debugging) but this is what I am actually trying to do and I cannot find it through search anywhere.

I know there are other ways to manipulate strings but then I also know you can do some really cool tricks with LINQ and I just would like to know if there is a way to trim a string to a certain length with LINQ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's no method built in to System.Linq to do this, but you could write your own extension method fairly easily:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ToSystemString(this IEnumerable<char> source)
    {
        return new string(source.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, because `object.ToString` exists on all .NET objects, you would have to give the method a different name so that the compiler will invoke your extension method, not the built-in `ToString`.

As per your comment below, it's good to question whether this is the right approach. Because `String` exposes a lot of functionality through its public methods, I would implement this method as an extension on `String` itself:

```
/// <summary>
/// Truncates a string to a maximum length.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value">The string to truncate.</param>
/// <param name="length">The maximum length of the returned string.</param>
/// <returns>The input string, truncated to <paramref name="length"/> characters.</returns>
public static string Truncate(this string value, int length)
{
    if (value == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
    return value.Length <= length ? value : value.Substring(0, length);
}
```

You would use it as follows:

```
string SomeText = "this is some text in a string";
return SomeText.Truncate(6);
```

This has the advantage of not creating any temporary arrays/objects when the string is already shorter than the desired length.

Comment: Thanks. And this is an "ok" way to do things? Its part of a larger system where I am passing around a StringBuilder and `.Append()`ing a lot of data to generate a file. I know I shouldn't prematurely optimize but is using LINQ in the way you are suggesting wasting a lot of cpu/memory when there is a simpler way to do this? Put simply: Would you use this code to trim a string to a certain length in your own project?

Comment: @rtpHarry Good question; I personally wouldn't use LINQ to accomplish this, and have updated my answer with the approach I would choose.

Comment: Thanks for your additional feedback, I will update my code based on this :)

Answer (score 23):

Just create string

```
string res = new string(SomeText.Take(6).ToArray());
```

Also pay attention to string native methods

```
string res = SomeText.Substring(0, 6);
```

Comment: Substring will throw if `SomeText` is shorter than six characters; I assumed that the OP wanted a method that behaved like `Take` (i.e., returns at most that many characters, but fewer (with no exception) if the input string is shorter).

Answer (score 8):

I've run into this myself a few times and use the following:

```
string.Join(string.Empty,yourString.Take(5));
```

Answer (score 4):

`SomeText.Take(6)` will returns an [`IEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) of char of char, and `ToString` method will not return the suspected string you need to call it like the following:

```
string [] array = SomeText.Take(6).ToArray();
string result = new string(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this question when I was looking up about LINQ and string.

You can use `IEnumerable<char>` instead of `string` in returning data type.
You can also learn more about it at [How to query for characters in a string (LINQ) (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-query-for-characters-in-a-string-linq)

And here is the solution.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        foreach (var c in LinqString())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c);
        }
        //OR
        Console.WriteLine(LinqString().ToArray());
    }

    private static IEnumerable<char> LinqString()
    {
        //This is Okay too...
        //IEnumerable<char> SomeText = "this is some text in a string";

        string SomeText = "this is some text in a string";
        
        return SomeText.Skip(4).Take(6);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with C# 8 and later...

grab the last 6 digits (***fails*** if the input is less than 8 chars)

```
string SomeText = "this is some text in a string";
string result =  SomeText[^6..];
```

a protected version that will handle strings less then 6 chars...

```
string SomeText = "this is some text in a string";
string result = SomeText[^(Math.Min(6, SomeText.Length))..];
```